# select max with like mysql - php

Tags: php, mysql

php not Want To recognize the following line

```
$concatenado = $_POST['concatenado'];

$consult3= "SELECT MAX(alumno.codigo) as codigo2 from alumno WHERE alumno.codigo LIKE '%'".$concatenado."'%' ";
```

the browser just says array.

this is the mysql query:

```
SELECT MAX(codigo) as numero from alumno WHERE codigo LIKE "102482901%"
```

I tried this lines of code but does not work .

```
%'".$concatenado."'%
"%".$concatenado."%"
%'".$concatenado."'%'
```

Why?

Thank.

Comment: `"SELECT MAX(alumno.codigo) as codigo2 from alumno WHERE alumno.codigo LIKE '%$concatenado%' "`

Comment: For your string concatenation, `LIKE '%".$concatenado."%'` is correct. You can also do `LIKE '%$concatenado%'` since variables are automatically expanded in double-quoted strings.

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure because your user parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and you’re putting `$_POST` data directly into the query, creating a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: It does not work , Same Text ' array11 ' appears. independienmente select max works well ; works well regardless the like . When stop working together . why?

Comment: Tadman, I provide delivery at UN EXAMPLE similar to my question . Thank you.

Comment: Show the code! You say you're getting "array11" as output but this tells us nothing when we don't see what is outputting it. Two lines is not useful. At a guess I'd say your query is working fine but you don't know how to output the results...

Comment: Unless you include the DB calls in your example there is no way to interpret the output. You're probably getting an array back (guessing PDO?). In which case use `var_dump` to see where your value is hiding.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$concatenado = $_POST['concatenado'];
$consult3= "SELECT MAX(alumno.codigo) as codigo2 from alumno WHERE alumno.codigo LIKE '%".$concatenado."%'"; 
mysql_select_db($database_Brujula, $Brujula);
$Result3 = mysql_query($consult3, $Brujula) or die(mysql_error());
$numero= mysql_num_rows($Result3);
$row_Result3 = mysql_fetch_array($Result3);
print $row_Result3['codigo2'];
print $numero;

if ($numero!= 0){
    $id = $row_Result3['codigo2'];
    print $id;
    $id = $id + 1;
}else{

$inicializador = 001;
$id =  $concatenado.$inicializador;
}
print $id;
```

The code print 11, it can be?

Thanks